# Copy Recovery partition using Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup

I have a dell computer and I will be DBAN ing the HDD because it has a bad sector on it that is slowing down the system.

So I am wanting to copy the Recovery Partition to an image or another HDD. I am wanting a method that can apply to copying it both to an image or HDD so I can use this in the future. I also would like a method I can remmeber. I have stumbled across a few but most use

```
dd if=/dev/sdaX of=~/recovery_partition.img
```

or some sort. I really would like something I can remember (such as a GUI program) because I am new to Ubuntu and still trying to learn.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is a dd gui for hard disk cloning/partiton backup etc task called gdiskdump. But its not in official repository you can download it from 
https://launchpad.net/gdiskdump